# Yii2 always set header to "UTF-8 with BOM" for saving files

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, yii2

In Yii2 I have controller that save some texts from database to .csv file. It contains russian (cyrillic) language. The problem is when I open file in Excel, it has bad charset: Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð

For Mac OS and Windows users Excel charset result is the same. Opening in notepad is okey. BUT Notepad says it has coding "UTF-8 with BOM". If I save to "UTF-8" from notepad, Excel reads good .csv file.

Code:

```
Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
Yii::$app->response->charset = 'utf-8';
Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
Yii::$app->response->headers->add('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="myfile.csv"');
// header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8',true);
```

**Any ideas what might be wrong?** I tried a lot of charsets (windows-1251, cp1251), text/plain -- no results. **Moreover**, strange chars always the same even if I set charset to chinese or any other.

**It is like headers charset are not changed and always "UTF-8 with BOM".**

`Yii::$app->charset` is 'UTF-8', changing `text/csv` to `text/plain` or even `text/json`, or saving as .txt and open it in Excel - the same results.

Comment: did you check your `layouts/main.php` file? The charset might be hard coded there

Comment: yeah, `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: just another suggestion if you've not already done that: check page source header area. We might get a clue there. I can't regenerate your problem. Mine's set to UTF-8 by default